# Compute account balance up to every day in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have an accounts table in BQ with the following schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE if not EXISTS accounts (
  id int,
  updated_at DATE,
  amount float
);

INSERT INTO accounts VALUES
(1, '2020-01-01', 1),
(1, '2020-01-02', 2),
(2, '2020-01-01', 0),
(2, '2020-01-03', 1),
(2, '2020-01-04', 5);
```

For every day, I want to calculate the total amount sum of the rows that had an update time prior to that day, and using only the last row by id. In this case, the results would be:

```
2020-01-01,1 (id = 1 has amount = 1, id = 2 has amount = 0)
2020-01-02,2 (id = 1 has amount = 2, id = 2 has amount = 0)
2020-01-03,3 (id = 1 has amount = 2, id = 2 has amount = 1)
2020-01-04,7 (id = 1 has amount = 2, id = 2 has amount = 5)
```

How can I do that in BigQuery?

I have around 30k updates per day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select updated_at, sum(ifnull(amount, 0)) amount from (
  select id, updated_at, 
    last_value(amount ignore nulls) over(partition by id order by updated_at) amount
  from (select distinct id from data) ids,
  (select updated_at from (
    select min(updated_at) min_at, max(updated_at) max_at from data),
    unnest(generate_date_array(min_at, max_at)) updated_at
  ) 
  left join data using(id, updated_at)
)
group by updated_at
# order by updated_at
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]